# Как в функции map каждому элементу передавать не строку, а переменную?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

```
workersData.map(item => 
     <WorkerLabel 
      id={props.number}
      />)
```

Приведённый выше код приведёт к тому, что в поле `id` запишется строка, которая является текущим значением `props.number`, а мне нужно, что бы сформированные компоненты получали реальный, текущий `props.number`, т.е. уже сформированный элемент должен выглядеть так:
`<WorkerLabel id={props.number} />` А сейчас выглядит так: `<WorkerLabel id='57' />` .

Как это можно реализовать?

P.S. Мапить повторно нельзя. Мап у меня выполняется единожды.

Comment: в чем отличие текущего от реального-текущий? что творится вокруг мапа? и что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас при обновлении `props.number` произойдет re-render компонента и в компоненты `WorkerLabel` запишется актуальное значение `number`.